# Code needed to unhide very hidden sheets in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 11 worksheets in a workbook in excel. The first sheet is the main sheet, while the other 10 are set to very hidden.  I am trying to create a userform that will have a list box with 10 options, with each one corresponding to a specific very hidden sheet. I want a specific sheet to become visible when the "OK" button is pressed, based on which option was selected in the list box. Please Help!

Comment: Did you not ask this here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272742/unhiding-very-hidden-sheet-excel-vba

Comment: Yes, I did, but the suggestion did not work and no one answered my comment so I am trying again from a different angle. Apparently, everyone here likes to point out the obvious rather than actually assisting people with valid questions

Comment: As you've written it, this question is probably too broad. Your last question was much better-formed. Show us your code, and explain what part is broken. You're very unlikely to get useful, specific answers to a vague, "please write my code for me" sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide and unhide the sheets using their [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786(v=office.15).aspx) property.

Comment: Thank you for the simplistic answer, but I was looking for some help into code that would show a specific sheet based on a selection from a list bx in a userform since everything i've tried is not working.

Comment: You should show what's not working.